# what is wrong in this first item in gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

In this code i am able to create gridlayout. but the first item is in default view and the rest is like what i want. I try debug and I couldn't see what is wrong. Would you help me to solve this.

```java
        question="this is a sentence";

        String sLetter;

        String question = question.replace(" ", "");

        //char[] charAr = question.toCharArray();

        final ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int k = 0; k < question.length(); k++) {
            sLetter = Character.toString(question.charAt(k));
            letters.add(sLetter);
        }

        Collections.sort(letters);
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < letters.size();) {

            int count = recursiveMethod(letters,i,1);

            if (count>0) {
                //region text add
                View main_view = new View(context);
                main_view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                gridLayout.setColumnCount(7);
                if (question.length()<=7){
                    gridLayout.setRowCount(1);
                }else if (question.length()<12){
                    gridLayout.setRowCount(2);
                }else {
                    gridLayout.setRowCount(3);
                }
                GridLayout.Spec colSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,1);
                GridLayout.Spec rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                        rowSpan, colSpan);
                gridParam.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
                gridParam.setMargins(5, 10, 5, 10);


                final TextView tv = new TextView(context);
                tv.setText(letters.get(i).toUpperCase());
                tv.setId(i);
                tv.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relTv  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                relTv.addRule( RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                relTv.addRule( RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                tv.setLinksClickable(true);
                tv.setTextSize(0, 60);
                //tv.setLayoutParams(relTv);

                CardView cardView = new CardView(context);
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                cardView.setRadius(10);
                cardView.setCardElevation(5);

                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                final TextView textCount = new TextView(context);
                textCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParam  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                relParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, i);
                relParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i);
                textCount.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                textCount.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
                textCount.setTextSize(0, 30);
                textCount.setPadding(0,5,5,0);
                //textCount.setLayoutParams(relParam);

                relativeLayout.addView(tv,relTv);
                relativeLayout.addView(textCount,relParam);

                cardView.addView(relativeLayout);

                //llLetters.addView(tv, lp);
                gridLayout.addView(cardView,gridParam);

                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, tv.getText()+ "" + textCount.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                //llLetters.addView(gridLayout);
                //endregion
                i = i + count;
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }


        }
```

The first letter of image is at the top left. I want to show that at the bottom right side of the letter. Would you help me to solve problem? Thanks =)

[image]

Comment: the problem was in the first one ```A``` and already solved. thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
relParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, i);
relParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i);
```

If you pass a zero to `addRule`, it is interpreted as `false`. Therefore you say, that `ALIGN_BOTTOM` should be `false` in your first letter, when `i` is zero.

[See the documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#addRule(int,%20int))

> parameter: subject, int: the ID of another view to use as an anchor, or a boolean value (represented as RelativeLayout.TRUE for true or 0 for false).

Comment: In the first line, `i` should be `RelativeLayout.TRUE`. In th esecond, `i` should be the `id` of the view to which it must be aligned.

Comment: ```i``` actually an id but it is dynamic. son when i make ```i+1``` solves the problem. ;)